# ListView при выборе элемента списка - использовать его позицию в этой же активити

Tags: android, listview

```
     public Long typeId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
listType = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listType);
        userCursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * FROM table_type;", null);
        System.out.println("Найдено элементов: " + String.valueOf(userCursor.getCount()));
        listType.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        final String[] headers = new String[] {DBHelper.PROP_VALUE};
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);

        System.out.println(userAdapter);
        listType.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        listType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long checkId) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                    + checkId);
typeId = checkId;
        }
    });
}
public void add_type(View view){
System.out.println(typeId);
}
```

Есть код курсора, адаптера и заполнения самого listView, могу в логи вывести выделенную галкой позицию и передать ее в другую активити, но как передать ее в метод нажатия кнопки не могу понять public void add_type(View view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось слишком просто:
сначала пишем: `public Long typeId;`
затем:

```
listType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long checkId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                + checkId);
       typeId = checkId;
    }
});
```

и в

```
public void add_type(View view){
System.out.println(typeId);
}
```